# How can I get this program to count the vowels in the User's inputted word?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, count

I have a slight problem with displaying the vowels in a word that I input. I have vowels =  AEIOU. I was thinking maybe that was the problem, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to fix it.

Here's what it gives me:

Enter a word: ANTARTICA

Here are the vowels in ANTARTICA: AEIOU

Vowel count: 4

Process completed.

So as you can see, it counted the vowels, I just want them to be displayed also. How would I do that? (I'm a noob coder....)

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Java2106{
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new Solution();
}}


class Solution
{
    String word;
    int count;
    String vowels;

    Solution()
    {
        input();
        output();
    }

    public void input()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);

        out.print("Enter a word: ");
        word = scan.nextLine();


    }

    public void output()
    {
        vowels = "AEIOU";
        count = 0;

        out.println();
        out.print("Here are the vowels in " + word + ": " + vowels);


        for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++)
        {
            String let = word.substring(x,x+1);

            if (vowels.contains(let))
                count++;
        }

        out.println("\nVowel count: " + count);

    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to display exactly the same vowels you found in your text, you should have an additional variable to store the vowels there. For example some kind of `List`. Then each time you find a vowel just push it into this list and eventually print it.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare the letters you have to lowercase or ignore case both the letters. I have added one more method `java8()` which shows you how to solve this using Java 8 lambda functions.

I would highly recommend you to read basic Java for your own benefit and learn how to write a Java class as the below is not a good implementation for a class. Your logic is way too complex for a simple program like this so I would highly recommend you to go back to basics.

```
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java2106 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solution();
    }
}

class Solution {
    String word;
    int count;
    String vowels;

    Solution() {
        input();
        output();
        java8();
    }

    private void java8() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("Enter a word: ");
        word = scan.nextLine();
        List<Character> letters = convert(word.toLowerCase());
        letters.removeIf(c -> (c.charValue() != 'a' && c.charValue() != 'e' && c.charValue() != 'i' && c.charValue() != 'o' && c.charValue() != 'u'));
        System.out.println("Vowels in given word: " + letters.size());
        scan.close();
    }

    private List<Character> convert(String word) {
        List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (Character c : word.toCharArray()) {
            letters.add(c);
        }
        return letters;
    }

    public void input() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("Enter a word: ");
        word = scan.nextLine();
    }

    public void output() {
        vowels = "AEIOU";
        count = 0;
        out.println();
        out.print("Here are the vowels in " + word + ": " + vowels);
        for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
            String let = word.substring(x, x + 1);
            if (vowels.toLowerCase().contains(let.toLowerCase()))
                count++;
        }

        out.println("\nVowel count: " + count);

    }
}
```

One of the simple implementation:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java2106 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        for (char c : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            if (isVowel(c)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Vowels : " + count);
        scan.close();
    }

    private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of ways to do this.

You could have an array for the vowels like this:

```
char[] vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
```

Then do a simple for loop that goes to through every letter of your string word:

```
int count = 0;
String vowelsInWord = "";    

for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<vowels.length; j++){
        if(word.charAt(i).toLowerCase() == vowels[j]){
            vowelsInWord += word.charAt(i).toLowerCase(); 
            count++;
        }
    }    
}

System.out.println("Vowels in word: " + vowelsInWord);
System.out.println("Vowel Count: " + count);
```